Injecting a service in Angular using a Symbol does not work in Firefox
My Angular app works in Chrome.
export interface UserService {
  me(): Observable<Response<User>>;
}

export const UserServiceRef = Symbol();

----

providers: [
    {
      provide: UserServiceRef,
      useClass: UserServiceGqlImpl,
    },

However, I get this error in Firefox.
ERROR TypeError: WeakMap key Symbol() must be an object

If I change it this way, then it doesn't give the error anymore.
export const UserServiceRef = 'UserServiceRef';

Can anyone help me?

Why don't you use an injection token instead of a Symbol() which would be the obvious choice in Angular?

You could provide either a string or an InjectionToken - (Old Docs Recommended since it contains more detailed explanation) as an input to provide.
As per the docs:
provide ( any ):

An injection token. (Typically an instance of Type or InjectionToken, but can be any).

export const UserServiceRef = new InjectionToken<string>('UserServiceRef');
// export const UserServiceRef = 'UserServiceRef';
----

providers: [
    {
      provide: UserServiceRef,
      useClass: UserServiceGqlImpl,
    },


I still find it a bit creepy that it works fine in Chrome but not in Firefox. :)
